# Layout horizontally and multiple lines

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to layout a bunch of child `Views` horizontally. If children fill a row, they should allocate more space and continue the render process in the next row. This process should continue, as long as children are left to get rendered.

May I use this using Xamarin.Forms views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no wrapping layouts currently in `Xamarin.Forms`, but you can achieve this quid easily with a `RelativeLayout`, as it allows to have constraint for childs relative to its parent.